# display sticky header list from api

Tags: flutter, api, user-interface, flutter-layout

Greeting to all,
I have made a list view using a sticky header where I am displaying the header list and sublist that I am getting from the API response. i am getting the data but I am stuck for displaying it in tile or card list like wise.
below is the image of how I am getting the data -:
[image]

and below is the code for sticky header -:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:sticky_headers/sticky_headers.dart';
import 'package:vcura/Model/Vaccination/Get_Vaccine.dart';
import 'package:vcura/Model/Vaccination/Get_Vaccine_ByID.dart';
import 'package:vcura/Provider/auth_provider.dart';
import 'package:vcura/Screens/home/collapsibleDrawer.dart';
import 'package:vcura/Services/Vaccination/Vaccineservice.dart';
import 'package:vcura/Widgets/custom_loader.dart';

class VaccinationPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _VaccinationPageState createState() => _VaccinationPageState();
}

class _VaccinationPageState extends State<VaccinationPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool isloading = false;
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  bool drawerOpen = true;

  var newFormat = DateFormat("dd-MM-yy");

  GetVaccine _vaccine = GetVaccine();
  GetVaccineById vaccineById = GetVaccineById();
  VaccineService vaccineService = VaccineService();

  var idSet = <String>{};
  var header = <dynamic>[];

  // var subtitle = [];
  List<VaccineModel> subtitle = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getdata();
  }

  Future getdata() async {
    setState(() {
      isloading = true;
    });
    String authToken = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false).token;
    GetVaccine vaccine = await vaccineService.Getvaccine(authToken);
    setState(() {
      _vaccine = vaccine;
      for (var d in _vaccine.data) {
        if (idSet.add(d.vaccineAgeCriteria)) {
          header.add(d.vaccineAgeCriteria);
        }
      }
    });
    setState(() {
      isloading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      drawerScrimColor: Colors.transparent,
      extendBody: true,
      drawer: ComplexDrawer(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: InkWell(
          child: Icon(
            Icons.menu,
            color: Colors.indigo,
          ),
          onTap: () {
            if (drawerOpen) {
              scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
            } else {
              return null;
            }
          },
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          'Vaccination',
          style: GoogleFonts.ubuntu(
            fontSize: 30,
            color: Colors.indigo,
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        actions: [
          InkWell(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Icon(
                Icons.search,
                color: Colors.indigo,
                size: 30,
              ),
            ),
            onTap: () {},
          ),
        ],
        elevation: 1,
      ),
      body: isloading
          ? CustomLoader(size: 50, color: Colors.indigoAccent)
          : Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 16),
              child: Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  child: ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    subtitle = _vaccine.data
                        .where((i) => i.vaccineAgeCriteria == header[index])
                        .toList();
                    print(subtitle.map((e) => e.vaccine));
                    return StickyHeaderBuilder(
                      builder: (context, stuckAmount) {
                        stuckAmount = stuckAmount.clamp(0.0, 1.0);
                        return Container(
                          height: 100.0 - (50 * (1 - stuckAmount)),
                          color:
                              Color.lerp(Colors.blue, Colors.red, stuckAmount),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          child: Text(
                            '${header[index]}',
                            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      content: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Column(
                          children: List<int>.generate(1, (index) => index)
                              .map(
                                (item) => Container(
                                  height: subtitle.length * 50.0,
                                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                  child: ListTile(
                                    title: Text(
                                        '${subtitle.map((e) => e.vaccine)}'),
                                  ), //_vaccine.data[index].vaccine
                                ),
                              )
                              .toList(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  })),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

below is a sample of data that I am getting -

```
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "0616c0b6-d798-08d974ba51cb",
      "vaccine": "Bacillus Calmette–Guérin (BCG)",
      "vaccineAgeCriteria": "Birth",
      "dose": 1,
      "vaccineDate": "1996-12-31T18:30:00"
    },
    {
      "id": "1e109992-d79b-08d974ba51cb",
      "vaccine": "Diptheria, Tetanus and Pertussis vaccine (DTwP 1)",
      "vaccineAgeCriteria": "6 weeks",
      "dose": 1,
      "vaccineDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
    },
    {
      "id": "a985b9d5-d7a3-08d974ba51cb",
      "vaccine": "Haemophilus influenzae type B (Hib 2)",
      "vaccineAgeCriteria": "10 weeks",
      "dose": 1,
      "vaccineDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
    },
    {
      "id": "1597403a-d7a4-08d974ba51cb",
      "vaccine": "Rotavirus 2",
      "vaccineAgeCriteria": "10 weeks",
      "dose": 1,
      "vaccineDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
    },
  ],
  "exceptionInfo": null,
  "message": null,
  "messages": null,
  "isSuccess": true
}
```

please help.

Comment: do you want to show your data in tile or card list wise?

Comment: actually in both in 2 different pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `ListTile` with the `ListView.builder`.

```
ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: ScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: subtitle.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(subtitle[index].vaccine),
            );
          },
        ),
```

Comment: and the list. generate that i have used. should I remove that?

Comment: just replace your `ListTile`

Comment: Glad to help you.Happy coding!